# Google Admob Doesn't Display

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, admob

When ı test my app on emulator or real device (Android only) when I set  admob isTesting = false not display ads but when ı set isTesting = true display test ads what is the problem ?

```
private options: AdOptions = {
    adId: 'adID',
    adSize:AdSize.BANNER,
    position: AdPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER,
    margin: 0,
    isTesting: false,
    // npa: true
  };
```

Comment: isTesing : false should be in release build only .. if you are checking it on debug build it should be true

Comment: Nothing wrong here .. if you want to use isTesing : true. build should be Release build

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing ads with isTesting is true, there is no problem with your code. But there is a delay with real ads and sometimes there is just no ads to show. Especially for new app.
Don't forget to check is there is any errors message in Android Studio.
Make sure your App ID and Ads ID are good.
Make sure your Admob account is good.

Comment: Should ı publish my app any market for real ads ?

Comment: Admob use offer/demands to show ads. Your app request ads, if there is none : no ad is shown. Most of the time it's because there is not enough traffic to analyse the population requesting ads. After some times, ads will show. If your app is not published, you should stay with "isTesting: true" or you could be banned. If you have other apps, you can also start displaying ads of your other apps in this app, it should work.